# TF400889 Long path error received from TFS

Tags: visual-studio-2013, tfs, tfvc

Can someone please help me out with this? I tried using long path tool but they want me to pay in order to delete the folder. However I cant find the file the system is complaining about. I went to the folder

[image: Error]

> C:\Users\Casey\Desktop\Workspace\LegalHoldings\Sprints\Sprint5\Expunctions\LegalHoldings.Expunctions.Service.External\ServiceReferences\FillingReviewMDEService\LegalHoldings.Expunctions.Service.External.FilingReviewMDEService.GetFeesCalculationsResponse.datasource

This file:

FilingReviewMDEService.GetFeesCalculationsResponse.datasource

Does not exist in the folder?!?!?!

I don't know what to do, I have been reading a lot of work-arounds online however most people suggest using long path tool but I remember having this issue in the past but I cant remember how I solved. I believed it was something to do with the Developer Command prompt and resetting some paths.

All help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Your path name is too long. Your folder structure is too deep.

Comment: **1.** Could you please fix the broken image link & inline them into this question properly, such that we don't have to go to another site to see the image?

Comment: **2.** The path mentioned in your answer differs from the one in the image. The path in your question is <200 characters in length and should be valid.

Comment: I dont know why its broken the link is the same as the one underneath, the screen capture I use is Jing.

Comment: **3.** Please don't write titles in all caps. Your question won't receive more attention because of all caps; all it achieves is to make your question look like spam and to provoke downvotes.

Comment: Try mapping all or part of your path to a drive letter to shorten the path: http://superuser.com/questions/300098/how-do-i-map-a-local-path-to-a-drive-letter-in-windows-7

Comment: @stakx The path from the error and the one I copied are the same. When I went to that folder i cant find the file

FilingReviewMDEService.GetFeesCalculationsResponse.datasource

However I can find other files similar to that one here is a screen capture

http://screencast.com/t/qZoprbu2Y

Comment: @Lostaunaum: No, the paths are not the same. The path in the screenshot contains the fragment `Expunctions.Service` twice; your cited path contains the same only once. You're missing some parts in the latter half of the path.

Comment: Updated tags and took file name from the screenshot into the command text.

Comment: Thank you guys for all the tips and making this question look decent I really appreciate the time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if you're even using the data binding features which the `.datasource` file is generated for, but turning that off in your service reference configuration by manually editing the `.svcmap` file would solve your problem.

[image]

After editing make sure you use the <kbd>Update Reference</kbd> feature to get rid of the unwanted file:

[image]

The second step would be to not map `$/` to your user profile in your workspace mapping, but `$LegalHoldings/Sprints/Sprint5/Expunctions` to something like `C:\Workspace\Sprint5` specifically that would drastically reduce the path depth required for your project.

If TFS still has a pending change for this file, you can use the `tf` utility from your workspace folder

```
C:\Users\Casey\Desktop\Workspace\LegalHoldings> tf undo $LegalHoldings/Sprints/Sprint5/Expunctions/LegalHoldings.Expunctions.Service.External/ServiceReferences/FillingReviewMDEService/LegalHoldings.Expunctions.Service.External.FilingReviewMDEService.GetFeesCalculationsResponse.datasource
```

to get rid of the pending change.

Comment: Thank you Guys, I am going to go ahead and download my project directly into my C file, it seems like this is the best solution to this problem.

Answer (score 7):

In VS/TFS 2012, I found this helpful:

[Open TFS Explorer] -> [Right click the root folder] -> Advanced->'Remove Mapping...'

[image]

Then, you can change the path:

[image]

HTH

Comment: Thanks bro all you guys have been really helpful with this issue!

Comment: you use dark setting toooooo!?!?! yes,I think this is the most straight forward answer

Comment: Thanks Moi, and yes - I use dark settings, it saves energy = less woodcutting :-)

Answer (score 6):

Usually these problems can be solved by shortening the paths higher up the tree.

It looks like your local path is the problem, so try mapping your code to a shorter root folder (e.g. C:\code rather than c:\users\Casey\desktop\workspace...)

Alternatively, you may be able to rename some mid level folders in your tfs structure to shorten the paths. But that's more extreme and probably not necessary in this case.